# Oracle SCHEMA Based XML DB

Tags: oracle, xsd

I am using schema based XML DB Column in one of oracle Table. I am using 30 nodes in XSD(schema) and the table performance is good.
I am thinking to increase the limit of nodes to 300 or more say 1000(Internally oracle treat each schema node as a column so we can have only 1000 nodes in XSD). But  am not sure what impact will be on the performance of of such big table.

If any one has anyone has experience or any reference please guide. I am trying understand how oracle XML DB work with Schema registration.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm..Performance is always subjective, and based on more than the query / data.

This might get you started:
http://www.orafaq.com/node/508

If you need references, oracles homepage is a really good start.

Have a look around, there is lots of information (too much sometimes actually) :-)
[oracle xml schema basics](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb05sto.htm)